# User is unable to enter the value of the string variable

Tags: java

User is unable to enter the value of the string variable.

This is the program:

```
import java.io.*;
public class testing
{
  char a;
  int b;
  double c;
  String d;
  public void method() throws IOException
  {
     BufferedReader p=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     System.out.println("Enter a variable of type 'char'");
     a = (char)p.read();
     System.out.println("Enter a variable of type 'string'");
     d = p.readLine();
     System.out.println("Enter a variable of type 'integer'");
     b = Integer.parseInt(p.readLine());
     System.out.println("Enter a variable of type 'double'");
     c = Double.parseDouble(p.readLine());
     System.out.println("Your values are: string-" +d +", integer-" +b +", double-" +c);
  }
}
```

Can someone see a problem?

Comment: please format your code. my eyes hurt..

Comment: the one who will edit this question will get 100 points :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar 100 points for me?

Comment: @Dukeling : Please let me know account number, I will transfer.

Comment: @FahimParkar It's `12STUcK8iN3ACc9NUM4GEN22PLs7HelP335`. No idea why it's so long, that's just the number they gave.

Comment: @Dukeling : Who gave?

Comment: @FahimParkar The account number generator people. There at that place at the corner of the internet. Just past Joke street.

Comment: @Dukeling : but from where? SO? or ur bank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it, your program works as expected. The only issue is that you use `read` to read the char, but no user input will be seen by Java until the user presses Enter. See my test run:

```
Enter a variable of type 'char'
cchar
Enter a variable of type 'string'
Enter a variable of type 'integer'
12
Enter a variable of type 'double'
12
Your values are: string-char, integer-12, double-12.0
```

Comment: but I want the user to be able to give the valuue for string as well, I am sorry but i didn't really get you; actually I am a beginner in java and this is my third program...

Comment: Look closely at my input: I entered "cchar" and got `a == 'c'` and `d.equals("char")`. The string value was read, only not in the order you expected. To correct this you must read the char using `readLine()`, just as you use it for everything else.